# sudo apt-get update : Could not connect to localhost:9999 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)

Tags: apt, updates, sudo, localhost

```
turtlebot@turtlebot-bot:~$ sudo apt-get update

Err:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com xenial InRelease Could not connect to localhost:9999 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)

Err:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com xenial-updates InRelease Unable to connect to localhost:9999:

Err:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com xenial-security InRelease Unable to connect to localhost:9999:

Err:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com xenial-backports InRelease Unable to connect to localhost:9999:

Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/flexiondotorg/minecraft/ubuntu xenial InRelease Could not connect to localhost:9999 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)

Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate-dev/welcome/ubuntu xenial InRelease Unable to connect to localhost:9999:

Err:7 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Could not connect to localhost:9999 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)

Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate-dev/xenial-mate/ubuntu xenial InRelease Unable to connect to localhost:9999:

Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-pi-flavour-makers/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease Unable to connect to localhost:9999:

Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireshark-dev/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease

Unable to connect to localhost:9999: Reading package lists... Done

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/dists/xenial/InRelease Could not connect to localhost:9999 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease Unable to connect to localhost:9999:

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/dists/xenial-security/InRelease Unable to connect to localhost:9999:

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease Unable to connect to localhost:9999:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/flexiondotorg/minecraft/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease Could not connect to localhost:9999 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease Could not connect to localhost:9999 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate-dev/welcome/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease Unable to connect to localhost:9999:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate-dev/xenial-mate/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease Unable to connect to localhost:9999:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-pi-flavour-makers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease Unable to connect to localhost:9999:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireshark-dev/stable/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease Unable to connect to localhost:9999:

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

turtlebot@turtlebot-bot:~$ lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Release: 16.04

Codename: xenial
```

PS: I didn't know the stack exchange culture. I was down voted by 5 when I published this same question in electronics.stackexchange.com as it was a question from turtlebot3-burgerbot. Anyways, I'm a novice in Linux realm and desperate to look for an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Please post the output of "dig ports.ubuntu.com" and "dig ppa.launchpad.net"

Comment: @Bernard; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> ports.ubuntu.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 33761
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ports.ubuntu.com.  IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ports.ubuntu.com. 700 IN A 91.189.88.150

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Jul 23 15:59:10 CDT 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 50

Comment: It looks like you configured your system to use a proxy (`localhost:9999`) at some point?

Comment: @Bernard dig ppa.launchpad.net   
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> ppa.launchpad.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 4745
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ppa.launchpad.net.  IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ppa.launchpad.net. 654 IN A 91.189.95.83

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Jul 23 16:39:51 CDT 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 51

Comment: @SujeetPoudel would be easier to read if you update your original questions but nevertheless, I can see that it is okay in resolving the IP's so that localhost:9999 is more likly a proxy issue as indicated by steeldriver

Comment: @steeldriver : How can I reconfigure again to restore?

Comment: @sujeet please try `sudo apt-get -oAcquire::Http::Proxy= update` and report back what happens (note the space between `=` and `update`)

Comment: @steeldriver  it is downloading something

Comment: @steeldriver yes  that command worked... and, i also installed firefox using: sudo apt-get -oAcquire::Http::Proxy= install firefox ... is there a way to fix the issue? thanks

Comment: @steeldriver firefox did install but it throws errors and doesn't open

Comment: @sujeet for a *permanent* fix you will need to find where the proxy setting is configured (`/etc/apt/apt.conf` or one of the files in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`) and remove or comment out the line like `Acquire::Http::Proxy`. Your firefox issue sounds like something unrelated - it's hard to tell without know **what** errors exactly

Comment: @steeldriver apt.conf showed these four  lines: Acquire::http::proxy "http://localhost:9999";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://localhost:9999";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://localhost:9999";
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks:localhost:9999";

Comment: @steeldriver there's nothing there in apt.conf.d

Comment: @steeldriver I commented those four lines and it works fine now. Thanks a lot. You can publish your answer and I will approve. Also please suggest me a good tutorial source for learning linux from scratch. I appreciate you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error

```
Could not connect to localhost:9999 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
```

suggests that your system is configured to use a local HTTP proxy for `apt` connections (and that no such proxy is running).

You can temporarily override this setting on the command line by passing an empty value `Acquire::Http::Proxy=` on the command line e.g.

```
sudo apt-get -oAcquire::Http::Proxy= update
```

If that works *and you believe that the proxy configuration is inappropriate*, then you can make the setting persistent by locating and either commenting out or removing any lines related to proxy configurations in your apt configuration files - `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and associated files in the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` directory - as well as an entry for HTTP you may find entries for HTTPS and/or socks protocols.

Comment: The empty-proxy trick didn't work for me, but I was able to solve the proxy problem by going into `All settings/Network/Network Proxy` and clicking "Apply system wide".