# Could not connect to localhost:9000

Tags: networking, 18.04, apt, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running **Ubuntu 18.04** in `Windows Subsystem for Linux`. When I try to "sudo apt-get update" , I have the following error:

```
myuser@GA014291L:/mnt/c/Users/myuser$ sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Could not connect to localhost:9000 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Could not connect to localhost:9000 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to localhost:9000:
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to localhost:9000:
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not connect to localhost:9000 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
```

I can ping my local Windows OS, as well as google.com with success.

Any idea, how to resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sudo apt-get update : Could not connect to localhost:9999 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058780/sudo-apt-get-update-could-not-connect-to-localhost9999-127-0-0-1-connect)

Comment: Agree with @Someone on the likely cause.  However, be aware that the proxy is likely configured somewhere on the Windows side for WSL.  I doubt the answer in that linked question is going to work, but please do give it a try.  If it doesn't work, can you disable the proxy on the Windows side?  Or, if you are sure you don't have a proxy in Windows, let us know.

Comment: indeed, it solved my problem